# Number of solutions to a functional equation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, exponential-function, functional-equations, absolute-value

> Let $f(x)=\mathrm e^{-x}\sin(x)g(x)$, where $g:\mathbb{R^+}\to (-M, M)$ for some positive real $M$. The number of solutions to the equation $|f(n_1)|+|f(n_2)|+\cdots+|f(n_k)|=1$, where all $n_i$ are natural:
>
> A) is infinite for some values of $k$ only
>
> B) is finite for all values of $k$
>
> C) can be infinite for all values of $k>1$
>
> D) none of these.

My approach: The only thing I did was that I noticed that for $x>0$, $f(x)<M$, so$$f(n_1)+f(n_2)+\cdots+f(n_k)<kM.$$Therefore, $1<kM$, and thus $1/M < k$. However, this bound on $K$ only **ensures** a solution and contributes nothing in calculating the **number** of solutions. I do not have any idea on how to proceed further.

Since this was from a high school exam, a solution exists using elementary calculus techniques only.
The given answer is B.

Comment: it is sinx * g(x)

Comment: “$\sin xg(x)$” means “$(\sin x)\cdot g(x)$” or “$\sin (x g(x))$?

Comment: @Saad yes, g is continuous.

Comment: @AlexRavsky, I have edited the question.

Comment: Hint: $g(x)=0$ satisfies the conditions, but is such that the equation in $f$ has no solution. This seems to rule out A. If we are free to choose $M$, then the condition$=1$ is immaterial and can be replaced by $>0$.

Answer (score 2):

$\def\N{\mathbb{N}}\def\e{\mathrm{e}}$Option B is correct. To prove it, a stronger proposition needs proving by induction:

> **Proposition:** For any $k \in \N_+$ and $a > 0$, the equation $\sum\limits_{j = 1}^k |f(n_j)| = a$ has only finitely many natural solutions.

*Proof:* For $k = 1$, if $n_1 \in \N_+$ satisfies $|f(n_1)| = a$, then$$
a = |f(n_1)| = \e^{-n_1} · |\sin(n_1)| · |g(n_1)| \leqslant \e^{-n_1} · M \Longrightarrow n_1 \leqslant \ln\frac{M}{a},
$$
which implies that $|f(n_1)| = a$ has only finitely many natural solutions.

Now assume the proposition holds for $k$. If $n_1, \cdots, n_{k + 1} \in \N_+$ satisfy $\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{k + 1} |f(n_j)| = a$, without loss of generality assume that $|f(n_1)| \leqslant \cdots \leqslant |f(n_{k + 1})|$, then$$
\frac{a}{k + 1} \leqslant |f(n_{k + 1})| = \e^{-n_{k + 1}} · |\sin(n_{k + 1})| · |g(n_{k + 1})| \leqslant \e^{-n_{k + 1}} · M
$$
implies that $n_{k + 1} \leqslant \ln\dfrac{(k + 1)M}{a}$. Note that for each natural $n \leqslant \ln\dfrac{(k + 1)M}{a}$, the equation$$
\sum_{j = 1}^k |f(n_j)| = a - |f(n)|
$$
either has no natural solution if $|f(n)| \geqslant a$ or has only finitely many natural solutions if $|f(n)| < a$ by induction hypothesis, therefore $\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{k + 1} |f(n_j)| = a$ also has only finitely many natural solutions. End of induction.

---

As is pointed out by @AlexRavsky, the inductive step fails since $f(n_{k + 1})$ might be equal to $a$.

Comment: At the induction step it can happen that $|f(n_{k+1})|=a$ and then we cannot apply the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Unfortunately, the fix doesn’t work, see my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3666071/number-of-solutions-to-a-functional-equation/3669340#3669340).  I was writing a solution with the same idea as yours, but then I found this gap.

Comment: @AlexRavsky You're right.

Answer (score 0):

An answer depends on $M$. Since $|f(n)|< Me^{-n}|\sin (n)| \le Me^{-1}\sin 1\approx 0.31 M$ for each natural $n$, if $kMe^{-1}\sin 1\le 1$ then the equation $|f(n_1)|+|f(n_2)|+\cdots+|f(n_k)|=1$ has no natural solutions. Otherwise consider an arbitrary continuous function $g:\mathbb{R^+}\to (-M, M)$ such that $g(1)=\frac {e}{k\sin 1}<M$ and $g(n)=0$ for each natural $n>1$. Then $k|f(1)|=1$. Moreover, for each $k’>1$ if $n_i=1$ for each $1\le i\le k$ and $n_i>1$ for each $k+1\le i\le k’$ then $|f(n_1)|+|f(n_2)|+\cdots+|f(n_{k’})|=1$. So the latter equation has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: erm. there's a slight ambiguity in the problem statement I think. Idk if $M$ can be whatever you want

Comment: @mathworker21 Thanks. I edited the answer.

Comment: The given answer is B.